# Unexpected behaviour when multiprocessing with numpy arrays of different data types

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing

I've come upon an unexpected error when multiprocessing with numpy arrays of different data types. First, I perform multiprocessing with numpy arrays of type `int64` and run it again with numpy arrays of type `float64`. The `int64` runs as expected whereas the `float64` uses all available processors (more than I've allocated) and results in a slower computation than using a single core.

The following example reproduces the problem:

```
def array_multiplication(arr):

    new_arr = arr.copy()

    for nnn in range(3):

        new_arr = np.dot(new_arr, arr)

    return new_arr

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import numpy as np
    from timeit import timeit

    # Example integer arrays.
    test_arr_1 = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 100))
    test_arr_2 = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 100))
    test_arr_3 = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 100))
    test_arr_4 = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 100))

    # Parameter array.
    parameter_arr = [test_arr_1, test_arr_2, test_arr_3, test_arr_4]

    pool = Pool(processes=len(parameter_arr))

    print('Multiprocessing time:')
    print(timeit(lambda: pool.map(array_multiplication, parameter_arr), 
          number=1000))

    print('Series time:')
    print(timeit(lambda: list(map(array_multiplication, parameter_arr)), 
          number=1000))
```

will yield

```
Multiprocessing speed:
4.1271785919998365
Series speed:
8.102764352000122
```

which is an expected speed-up.

However, replacing `test_arr_n` with

```
test_arr_1 = np.random.normal(50, 30, size=(100, 100))
test_arr_2 = np.random.normal(50, 30, size=(100, 100))
test_arr_3 = np.random.normal(50, 30, size=(100, 100))
test_arr_4 = np.random.normal(50, 30, size=(100, 100))
```

results in

```
Multiprocessing time:
2.379720258999896
Series time:
0.40820308100001057
```

in addition to using up all available processors, where I've specified 4. Below are screen grabs of the processor usage when running the first case (`int64`) and second case (`float64`).

[image]

Above is the `int64` case, where four processors are given tasks followed by one processor computing the task in series.

[image]

However, in the `float64` case, all processors are being used, even though the specified number is the number of `test_arr`'s - that is, 4.

I have tried this for a number of array size magnitudes and number of iterations in the `for` loop in `array_multiplication`and the behaviour is the same. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with 62.8 GB of memory and an i7-6800k 3.40GHz CPU.

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a clarification: Is your question more than asking why floating point calculations take more computational effort than integer calculations?

Comment: @koalo Yes. My question is: Why does the multiprocessing take more time than the series computation for `float64`, but more importantly, why are all the processors being used when only 4 are specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected behaviour.

Numpy uses [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) internally (for some functions) which is highly optimized (Cache, SIMD, and depending on your implementation in use: Multithreading; some implementation-candidates Atlas, OpenBLAS, MKL) and is only slowed down with some outer multiprocessing (which has IO-based overhead and might hurt caching-behaviour too)!

Modern Ubuntu-versions come with a multithreaded BLAS implementation by default (earlier ones were limited to 1 or 2 threads).

The classic example of BLAS-based functions in numpy is `np.dot()`.

Most BLAS-implementations (all i know; saw some discussion [@Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/720664) for adding some limited support for discrete types into MKL) [only support floating-point types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830118/matrix-multiplication-for-integral-types-using-blas), so this is the reason, why these two codes behave differently (one highly optimized, the other is not; one hurt by multiprocessing, the other not).

Technically i would not call it an error, but it's an observation you describe!

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082610/what-am-i-missing-in-python-multiprocessing-multithreading/46082695#46082695).

Comment: This is interesting. Would you say that, in effect, there is 'compounded' multiprocessing going on, as in, `Pool` is allocating the tasks to 4 processors which in turn are allocating the `np.dot()` task to `n` more processors, creating `4n` processes (or something like that)? When I specify 2 processes in `Pool` there is actually a speedup, whereas 1 results in the same time as the series computation and 3 or more are slower.

Comment: This probably depends on the scheduler of your OS, but that's what i would expect. But one has to be careful about the specifics, e.g. processor, core, thread. I also don't think your example is a good one (where 2 processes might be a good thing), probably due to the outer copy and loop. Classic vectorization be faster in most cases for operations like this (skip MT completely). You can also try some matrix-multiplication (big one) without any other code to observe the number of threads in use with your implementation.